# Visual Studio 2010 - IDE issues with grid-views

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a strange issue with VS2010 in which the grid-views within the IDE sometimes mis-behave, they go into a state of constant re-painting very very slowly, which then causes the all other windows in the OS to re-paint, this gets stuck in an endless loop and causes the OS UI to pretty-much lockup, the only way to fix is to close VS2010 or minimize it.

Here is a detailed explaination (this just mentions Team Explorer but I've had the issue with a connection string dialog too):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/57ceb594-10ac-482c-bb3d-9a294a538d6c

My gut feeling is that maybe there's an issue just on my laptop (maybe graphics card issue?) that only affects VS2010.  It's SP1 by the way.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: I just tried to do some diagnosis when this issue occurs, so I opened up task manager, and that actually sorted the issue out, even after I've closed task manager, the re-painting stopped and everything worked as normal.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the solution to this, but Ctrl+Alt+Delete, then clicking Cancel seems to cause VS2010 to 'snap out of it'.